# three.js BufferGeometry blob code update error

Tags: javascript, three.js

I currently learning three js and I was following [this tutorial](https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@clayjohn/learning-3d-graphics-with-three-js-or-dynamic-geometry) however noticed that the code is invalid for the current version of threejs  and you can see the main change below. Going by this [document](https://sbcode.net/threejs/geometry-to-buffergeometry/) I've updated the bit of code to:

```
  var k = 1;
     
  const positions = sphere.geometry.attributes.position.array;
  for (var i = 0; i < positions.length - 2; i++) {
    const v = new THREE.Vector3(
      positions[i], 
      positions[i + 1], 
      positions[i + 2]
    ).normalize()
    .multiplyScalar(
      1 + 0.3 * noise.perlin3(
      positions[i] * k + time,
      positions[i + 1] * k,
      positions[i + 2] * k));
      positions[i] = v.x;
      positions[i + 1] = v.y;
      positions[i + 2] = v.z;
  }
  
 sphere.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
```

However as you can see from the snippet the vertex displacement is not smooth and does not resemble the tutorial. What I'm missing here?

```js
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas : document.getElementById('canvas'), antialias:true});
// default bg canvas color //
renderer.setClearColor(0x7b7b7b);
//  use device aspect ratio //
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
// set size of canvas within window //
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);




var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.z = 5;


var sphere_geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 128, 128);
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0x0000FF,
    shininess: 1000,
  })

var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphere_geometry, material);
scene.add(sphere);
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x798296)
scene.add(ambientLight)
const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5)
    directionalLight.position.set(5, 10, 7)
scene.add(directionalLight);
sphere.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;

var update = function() {

  // change '0.003' for more aggressive animation
  var time = performance.now() * 0.003;
  //console.log(time)

  //go through vertices here and reposition them
  
  // change 'k' value for more spikes
  var k = 1;
     
  const positions = sphere.geometry.attributes.position.array;
  for (var i = 0; i < positions.length - 2; i++) {
    const v = new THREE.Vector3(
      positions[i], 
      positions[i + 1], 
      positions[i + 2]
    ).normalize()
    .multiplyScalar(
      1 + 0.3 * noise.perlin3(positions[i] * k + time,                 positions[i + 1] * k,
      positions[i + 2] * k));
      positions[i] = v.x;
      positions[i + 1] = v.y;
      positions[i + 2] = v.z;
  }
  
 sphere.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
}

function animate() {
  sphere.rotation.x += 0.01;
  sphere.rotation.y += 0.01;

  update();
  /* render scene and camera */
  renderer.render(scene,camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}


requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://fariskassim.com/stage/rebel9/teaf/blob/v4/js/perlin.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can deform a sphere with noise, using `BufferGeometry`:

[image]

```js
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas : document.getElementById('canvas'), antialias:true});
// default bg canvas color //
renderer.setClearColor(0x7b7b7b);
//  use device aspect ratio //
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
// set size of canvas within window //
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);




var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.z = 5;


var sphere_geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 128, 128);
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0x0000FF,
    shininess: 1000,
  })

var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphere_geometry, material);
scene.add(sphere);
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x798296)
scene.add(ambientLight)
const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5)
    directionalLight.position.set(5, 10, 7)
scene.add(directionalLight);
sphere.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;

var update = function() {

  // change '0.003' for more aggressive animation
  var time = performance.now() * 0.003;
  //console.log(time)

  //go through vertices here and reposition them
  
  // change 'k' value for more spikes
  var k = 1;
  var v3 = new THREE.Vector3();   
  const positions = sphere.geometry.attributes.position;
  for (var i = 0; i < positions.count; i++) {
    v3.fromBufferAttribute(positions, i).setLength(k);
    let n = noise.perlin3(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z);
    v3.setLength(1 + 0.3 * n);
    positions.setXYZ(i, v3.x, v3.y, v3.z);
  }
  positions.needsUpdate = true;
  sphere.geometry.computeVertexNormals(); // don't forget to call this
}

function animate() {
  sphere.rotation.x += 0.01;
  sphere.rotation.y += 0.01;

  update();
  /* render scene and camera */
  renderer.render(scene,camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}


requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://fariskassim.com/stage/rebel9/teaf/blob/v4/js/perlin.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: This got me on the right path, I think the only thing that it needs is the time to get the vertices interpolating the values from the perlin noise, so: `let n = noise.perlin3(v3.x + time * 0.1, v3.y + time * 0.1, v3.z + time * 0.1);`

Comment: @Ivelazquez You know if this is the answer, you should probably mark it as so